# XPages app eating up all the hard disk space on the server

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

We recently had a error on the server that it had run out of memory and eventually we found the culprit to be this folder:

\Users\currentuser\AppData\Local\Temp\notes618068\xspstate

As soon as we bring the Domino server down (running on 9.0.1 - FP4 with HF3) and bring it back up, this error goes away until next time!

Has anyone experienced this problem and any advice or ideas on why this might be occurring?

**Update 16/12/15: IBM has now released a hotfix for this issue.**

Comment: We have a SPR open with IBM. They have explained that the setting xsp.persistence.mode=fileex means that most pages are saved on-disk (in the file system), except for a single page which is memory. However they have not addressed the failure of the server to clear the files after the JSF container expires the user session. We are still perusing this issue with them.

Comment: We finally have a SPR open with IBM with regards to this issue.

Comment: We now have a hotfix from IBM in case anyone else is interested or has similar issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That folder will be where sessions are saved to disk. I would check:

1. Applications where xsp property for number of pages to save has been increased to a high number
2. Applications where xsp property session timeouts have been changed to a high number. Even after a browser is closed, the session will still be held on disk until the tineout has passed - the server doesn't know the browser's been closed!
3. Applications with either of these and high numbers of users could be the cause
4. Applications with XAgents for REST or other transient access points that don't have viewstate="nostate" set (double-check case sensitivity, it's on XPage's All Properties). Otherwise those component trees get persisted. If they're used for REST access, each is a separate session, so the maximum number of pages never applies.

I don't know if the files in xspstate give any indiciation of the application. If so, it might help track down the culprit(s).

Comment: Many thanks Paul, a few things to check and try, will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Thanks for the XAgents property of viewState="nostate", let's see if that resolves the problem. Session timeout is not defined in our xsp properties file, which means it will accept the server default value. The content of the xspstate folder is some very large ser files. We were fine until last week on 8.5.3 with the same code and same amount of users, so wondering what else is wrong! Anything to do with garbage collection. Anyway it would be nice to stop Domino from eating up all the HD space, there should be a limit somewhere at least!

Comment: Paul I would be happy to accept your answer, since this turned out to be a software bug which neither of us could have predicted.